# Air as3 app closing on android device doesn't trigger NetGroup.Neighbor.Disconnect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder, netgroup

Im building a turn based p2p game in flash builder, but just run into a problem with how to handle a disconnect user action.
On desktop when testing multiple swfs (and a debugging window) opened the "NetGroup.Neighbor.Disconnect" event is triggered if one of these windows are closed, 
but when the app is tested on a (Android) device everything works properly except when the application is closed (not just deactivated) this disconnect event is not triggered.

Also it seams that there is no way to catch any event on application closing on a real device where the connection could be closed. Forcing this disconnection when the application is deactivated (sent to background) is not a good solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with is to use a keep alive messaging for each users.
When a connected app is terminated this keep alive sending stops, so the disconnect handling can be called after some time at every other running app.